# How to construct ActiveRecords queries for JSONB data

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, ruby-on-rails-6

I would like to change the `json` columns in an app to `jsonb` and I am interested to explore the new query capabilities for jsonb data.

For example, say a table has a "payload" field in `jsonb` format, how can I query and render selected data items inside the "payload" hash?

Can anyone recommend good resources or tutorials where I can start my journey?

Comment: I found this link: https://medium.com/@tara.kelly16/custom-json-rendering-in-rails-7c68704c099e

Comment: Thank you for your response, Mark. This link shows some good examples for rendering `json` data. However, `jsonb` offers some distinct advantages and I would like to exploit the way that `jsonb` integrates relational queries with non-relational data inside a jsonb hash.

Comment: I am not sure ruby  have jsonb data type. I don't know anything about ruby. maybe you can write an postgresql function that return json then render the json on ruby.